# Energy ratio of signal

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, signal-detection, signal-power, signal-energy

What is the energy ratio of signal at frequency domain?

What is its mathematical formula at frequency domain and what can stand for?

I found it in this paper

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332075345_MVMD-MOMEDA-TEO_model_and_its_application_in_feature_extraction_for_rolling_bearings

and also I found this Matlab code about it at frequency domain

```
               d=hilbert(x(1,1:N));

                  c=abs(d);

                y1=(c-mean(c))/std(c,1);

                 y2=y1;

                ye=fft(y2);

                p=2*abs(ye)/N;

                  figure(1);

                plot(t,y2);

                plot((0:N/2-1)/N*fs,p(1:N/2),'b')

                  M=find(p==max(p(1:N/2)));

                      EnergyRatio= 
       (p(M(1))^2+p(2*M(1)-1)^2+p(3*M(1)-2)^2)/sum(p(1:N/2).^2);

                display(EnergyRatio);
```

I'll be grateful for your response

Comment: "energy ratio": never heard that term! Generally a ratio is between two things; so you will have to tell you where you saw that term

Comment: I saw this term in a cod Matlab program, I'll try to send the code

Comment: I edited the question, where I wrote code Matlab related to energy ratio, could you please make me figure out what is it for

Comment: you can find it also in this paper               https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332075345_MVMD-MOMEDA-TEO_model_and_its_application_in_feature_extraction_for_rolling_bearings

Comment: where's that code from? Random matlab code is really not a reason to wonder about some definition. People use the funniest names in code. Is the meaning as used in the paper really what you care about? Because if we explain the paper and it means something different than what you care about, we waste a lot of time.

Comment: also, the `EnergyRatio` is literally a ratio of energies. That explains the name. Voting to close as unclear what the question is!

Comment: I would like to know the expression as well as mathematic formula of energy ratio used in the above paper

Comment: The mathematical formula is right there in the Matlab (but whoever wrote that was relatively bad at Matlab, probably. This code looks very copied together and senselessly complicated. It clearly isn't code you would want to reuse; if the person writing it understand what they were doing as well as they demonstrate here, that'd be bad) Also, that is not a signal processing question. You have only linked to the paper, but not explained what you've understood about it and where you're stuck, rendering your question too unspecific. Please be very precise about what you need help with in the paper.

Comment: in this paper energy ratio is used as feauture to extract useful modes in ordr to reconstruct the signal, what I did not understand is how it is calculated , need its formula

Comment: Have you considered the one big formula that explicitly divides two energies, directly in figure 1, and the matching step 5 containing the term "energy proportion"? "Proportion" is just a different word for "ratio".

Answer (score 0):

"energy ratio", "energy proportion": Just terms introduced by the paper to describe how much of the total energy is in each IMF. They're not terms that are used anywhere else, which is why giving us code without context just confused very much. These terms are just English words outside of your paper! Inside of your paper, they describe literally a ratio of energies.

Compare the big ratio of energies formula in the flow chart in Fig. 1 of your paper, and the matching "Step 5." in the description of the algorithm (which uses the wording "energy proportion").

Also note how Table 2 and its description, which again explain that you add up the energies from the IMFs until you cross a threshold, exactly as shown in Fig. 1.

The code you copied from somewhere else, omitting any context, is useless in context of this paper; it contains squares of squares, which appears nowhere in the paper. Together with the poor code quality I'd say you want to ignore the code.